# R shiny - Unable to read input values when calling server via callModule

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

```
Main app.R

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "R shiny Dashboard")


source("projects/customers/ui.R", local = TRUE)
customers_server <-
  source("projects/customers/server.R", local = TRUE)$value

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    id = "sidebar",
    menuItem("Home", tabName = "home"),
    menuSubItem("Customers", tabName = "customers")
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "home",
          tags$div(
            HTML(
              '<h2 style="font-family:Arial; color:black;">Welcome</h2>'
            )
          )),
  tabItem(tabName = "customers",
          customers_ui("customers_ui"))
))

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    req(input$sidebar)  # Ensure 'sidebar' input is available before executing the rest of the code
    
    tab <- input$sidebar
    
    if (tab == "home") {
      # do nothing for home page
    }
    
    if (tab == "customers") {
      shinyjs::show("loading")
      callModule(customers_server, "customers_ui", session = session)
      shiny::removeModal()  # Remove the modal once the data is loaded
      shinyjs::hide("loading")
    }
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(
  ui = ui,
  server = server,
  options = list(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 9999)
)

projects/customers/ui.R

source("projects/customers/modules.R")

customers_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    
    # Set the title of the page
    titlePanel(" Dashboard"),
    
    # Create tabs for Drift Metrics and Model Monitoring
    tabsetPanel(
      id = "tabs",
      tabPanel("Customer Stats", customerStatsUi(ns("customer_stats")))
    )
  )
}

Projects/customers/server.R

source("projects/customers/modules.R")

customers_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ns <- session$ns
  
  timer <- reactiveTimer(2000)  # 2 second delay
  
  observeEvent(input$tabs, {
    shinyjs::show("loading")
    timer()  # Trigger the timer
  })
  
  customersStats(ns("customer_stats"))
  
  observeEvent(timer(), {
    shinyjs::hide("loading") 
  })
}

projects/customers/modules.R

customerStatsUi = function(id) {
  
  ns = NS(id)  # Create a namespaced ID function
  
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      tags$head(tags$style(
        HTML(
          "
            .skin-blue .main-header .navbar {
              background-color: #1a8cff;
            }
            .skin-blue .main-header .logo {
              background-color: #1a8cff;
            }
            .box.box-primary {
              border-top-color: #1a8cff;
            }
            .sidebar-menu>li.active>a {
              border-left-color: #1a8cff;
            }
            .selectize-input {
              border-color: #1a8cff;
            }
          "
        )
      )),
      useShinyjs(),  # Enable shinyjs
      box(
        title = "Settings",
        width = 12,
        status = "primary",
        solidHeader = TRUE,
        column(
          4,
          dateInput(
            ns("date"),
            "Date:",
            value = Sys.Date()
          ),
          actionButton(ns("submit"), "Submit"),  # Add submit button
          textOutput(ns("selectedDate"))
        )
      )
    )
  )
}

customersStats = function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns = session$ns  # Create a namespaced ID function
    print(input$date)
    output$selectedDate <- renderText({
      req(input$submit)
      paste("Selected date:", input$date)
    })
  })
}
```

The print(input$date) prints NULL. I'm unable to read any input$ values. If I call the server function directly instead of using callModule, everything works fine.

Could someone help me identify what I'm doing wrong here.

Tried experimenting with the code by print(ns("date")) which prints - [1] "customers_ui-customers_ui-customer_stats-date"

Does it mean I cannot access the date as input$date?`

Comment: Please make your example *reproducible*.  Accessing the `date` input from your `customerStats` module is possible.  But it's bad practice (it breaks the concept of a module being self contained) and fragile (different module instances will use different widget IDs).  Better to return the required values from the module seever function and monitor them in the main app server.  See, for example, section 19.3 of [this page](https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-modules.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Plots from inside a renderUI in a Shiny Module to main Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67905365/passing-plots-from-inside-a-renderui-in-a-shiny-module-to-main-server)